# VSTS Load test reports

Tags: visual-studio, report, load-testing

We've setup some different load tests and need to generate/send the result pr. e-mail, a link, pdf or similar. The output and metrics are saved to a database (resultstore), but I haven't been able to find too much information on how to generate a report without having visual studio. One thing that comes into mind, is creating a custom report in reporting service (any one know of existing reports I could use?). 
Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Surely someone must have been messing with some kind of report feedback for nightly builds, load tests etc. I've found the excel report feature, but I have not been able to invoke this report with cli/script yet.

Comment: If you'll look at the Report DB (LoadTest2010) you'll find out that its structured in a pretty simple way to understand including Summary Views.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ended up with creating a report myself using reporting services. If I can make generic enough, I'll post it here.